# Porque regex es tan lento

Tags: regex, validación, rendimiento

hace poco me ha surgido la necesidad de validar algunas propiedades usando Regex, tras hacerlo, y ver lo que refiere a performance, noto que es muchísimo más lento que, en mi caso (C#) realizar una validación similar usando linq

Por ejemplo (C#)

```
List<string> Lista = new List<string>();
            
            for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
            {
                //Método que devuelve un número que cumple
                Lista.Add(GenerarNumeroCorrecto());
                //Método que devuelve un campo que no cumple 
                Lista.Add(GenerarNumeroIncorrecto());
            }           

            Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();            

            s.Start();            

            foreach(string cadena in Lista)
            {
                if((!cadena.Any(c => !char.IsDigit(c))) && cadena.Length == 7)
                {
                    //true
                }
            }

            s.Stop();
            var LinqElapsed = s.Elapsed;

            s.Reset();
            s.Start();
            Regex reg = new Regex("^\\d{7}$");
            foreach(string cadena in Lista)
            {
                if (reg.IsMatch(cadena))
                {
                    //true
                }

            }
            s.Stop();
            var RegexElapsed = s.Elapsed;
            
            Console.WriteLine("Linq: demora {0} \nRegex: demora {1}",LinqElapsed,RegexElapsed);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

En el ejemplo anterior, el output es el siguiente:

> Linq: demora 00:00:00.0001753
>
> Regex: demora 00:00:00.0007208

La solución con Regex es más de 4 veces más lenta, y de aquí la duda, **¿por qué regex es tan lento?**, cuál es su funcionamiento real detrás que provoca esto?

Comment: Lo tardado fue construir la instancia, por lo regular si las ocupas muy seguido se construyen una vez y se reutilizan osea el IsMatch

Comment: @shop350 toda la razón, si la instancia la creo fuera del `Stopwatch` el tiempo disminuye una barbaridad

Comment: Por otro lado, una regex es en esencia un "mini-programa" expresado en forma de secuencia de códigos ascii. Al crearla se "compila" a una secuencia binaria que representa el mini-programa a ejecutar. Cada `IsMatch()` ejecuta ese miniprograma (que es una máquina de estados que va avanzando de un estado a otro guiado por los caracteres de la cadena de entrada). Si al finalizar el mini-programa se está al final de la cadena, se tiene un match. Dependiendo de la complejidad de lo que quieras hacer, puede ser más rápido testearlo tú mismo por otro método, como en este caso.

Comment: Por cierto que tu linq aún puede optimizarse si cambias el orden de la expresión `&&`, pues supongo que C#, como otras variantes de C, tenga haga _shortcut_ a la hora de evaluar una expresión booleana, es decir, si ve que el primer término de un "and" es Falso, ya no evalúa el resto de términos. Por tanto si comienzas por mirar si la longitud es 7, cuando no lo es ya no necesitará siquiera comprobar si los caracteres son dígitos. Este tipo de optimizaciones no las puedes hacer con la regexp (a menos que el "compilador" de regexp ya las haga automáticamente)

Comment: @abulafia espectacular tu comentario, muchas gracias!

Comment: En general, si vas a medir tiempos (*benchmark*) una única medida puede ser insuficiente; en un ordenador pasan montones de cosas al mismo tiempo y puede que lo que midas no sea tanto la velocidad de tu código como el SO empezando algún proceso y parando el tuyo un instante, etc. Especialmente si el tiempo a medir es tan bajo. Lo recomendable es repetir las observaciones muchas veces veces y ver los datos estadísticos (la media como mínimo, pero también la variación es interesante).

Comment: @sjuan76 Si es `CPU time` en lugar de `real time`, no importa la cantidad de procesos que hubiera en marcha. Aún así, una media siempre es algo positivo. @juan-salvador-portugal Aunque utilices una expresión regular sencilla, el motor es capaz de evaluar cosas mucho más complejas. El motor pueden ser miles de líneas de código. Y aunque no se ejecuten todas, cargar y utilizarlo aunque sea para un caso sencillo, tiene su coste. Si se intenta optimizar, se recomienda no utilizar Regexes para validaciones sencillas. @abulafia, creo que deberías responder la respuesta y que fuera aceptada

Comment: Como esta pregunta estaba estancada, he añadido mi respuesta junto con la de @abulafia como 'wiki de comunidad'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una expresión regular es en esencia un "mini-programa" expresado en forma de secuencia de códigos ascii.

Al crearla se "compila" a una secuencia binaria que representa el mini-programa a ejecutar.

Cada IsMatch() ejecuta ese miniprograma (que es una máquina de estados que va avanzando de un estado a otro guiado por los caracteres de la cadena de entrada). Si al finalizar el mini-programa se está al final de la cadena, se tiene un match.

Aunque utilices una expresión regular sencilla, el motor es capaz de evaluar cosas mucho más complejas. El motor pueden ser miles de líneas de código. Y aunque no se ejecuten todas, cargar y utilizarlo aunque sea para un caso sencillo, tiene su coste.

No por ello significa que tenga que ser lento, pero simplemente para algunos casos será más rápido (aunque probablemente inperceptible) la otra solución con `linq`.

Así pues, si se intenta optimizar (si fuera *realmente* necesario), se *podría* recomendar no utilizar Regexes para validaciones sencillas.