# Validar un campo de matrícula de vehículo o un dni en c#

Tags: c#, validación

Hola estoy intentando crear campos en C# de forma que puedan sean validados, uno de ellos es la matrícula de un vehículo con el siguiente formato 0000 AAA. Esto es, 4 dígitos, un espacio, y tres letras en mayúscula.

El otro sería un ID empleado que empieza siempre con la letra V y le siguen los dígitos (sólo los números) del dni.

Mas allá de insertar un MaskTextBox y darle una máscara no sé cómo hacer esto, mi conocimiento es muy limitado, y agradecería cualquier ejemplo (no busco que nadie me haga el trabajo, con un ejemplo me vale).
¡Gracias!

Comment: Si es Windows Forms, lee [esto](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/user-input-validation-in-windows-forms) y usa tambien ErrorProvider. [Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2) tienes un ejemplo mas o menos completo

Comment: Si son matrículas españolas ten en cuenta que no pueden contener vocales :-)

Comment: Ya que vamos a eso, tampoco admite Ñ ni Q :)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Podes validarlo usando un regex bastante sencillo, algo así `\b[0-9]{4}[A-P R-Z]{3}\b` [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fxOBGt/3)

Comment: Aun cuando no busques que alguien haga tu trabajo si debes presentar por lo menos un intento, y si te equivocas o necesitas ayuda puedes agregar tu pregunta con una duda especifica. Te invito a que te des unos minutos  y tomes un [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por este sitio.

Comment: Gracias a todos por los regex, me han servido de mucho para aprender el funcionamiento. Ahora podría decir que he aprendido y además de 3 maneras. 1. manejando la máscara, 2. con regex y 3. con funciones específicas... voy a intentar poner un ejemplo de la función para comprobar la fecha...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hay diversas formas de hacerlo pero la más correcta en mi opinión es con expresiones regulares. Te recomendaría que te vieras algo de ello en este enlace que te dejo por aquí (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) de un ejemplo en C# y que puede ser aplicable a cualquier lenguaje de programación. De hecho aquí te muestro un ejemplo de una actividad en mis inicios de mi formación en programación web en JavaScript pero que funciona exactamente igual en C#.

Se trata de un método que comprueba si una cadena de caracteres cumple con la regla de que se trate de 8 dígitos y una letra o una letra (X, Y, Z), 7 dígitos y otra letra, como un DNI:

```
function checkMyForm() {
    /*Campo donde obtengo mi valor*/
    let dni = document.getElementById("dniField").value;
    /**
     *  Expresión regular que determina que:
     *            1º) 1 caracter que puede ser numero o letra incluy. minusculas y mayusculas  --> [\d|(x-zX-Z)]
     *            2º) 7 dígitos --> \d{7}
     *            3º) 1 letra incluy. minusculas y mayusculas --> [a-zA-Z]
     *
     *  Por último resaltar que /^ indica donde empieza la exp. regular y $/ 
     *  lo que determina su fin.
    **/                           
    let regExp = /^[\d|(x-zX-Z)]\d{7}[a-zA-Z]$/;

   //Con este método es suficiente para comprobarlo (regExp.test())
    if (regExp.test(dni)) {
        result.innerHTML = "Everything ok!!";
    } else {
        result.innerHTML = "Wrong format, try again!!";
    }

    /**
     * Por si como fue en mi caso, cumple con la expresion regular
     * pero le faltan caracteres se rellena a 0 sólo a la izquierda de la
     * cadena de caracteres de la variable 'dni'
    **/
    if (dni.length != 0 && dni.length < 10) {
        if (!/\d{7}|\d{8}/.test(dni)) {
            do {
                dni = "0" + dni
            } while (dni.length != 9);
        }


    } else {
        result.innerHTML = "Is not all filled properly, try again!!";
    }
    result.innerHTML += " " + dni;
}
```

Si te sirvió la ayuda o necesitas algo más de información acerca de ello por favor házmelo saber. 
Un saludo.

Comment: Si el tiempo permite evitar el uso de regex, siempre es mejor, por un lado, es muy lento, y por el otro es muy complicado de mantener (por su poca legibilidad)

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Por lo menos le ubieras dejado algun ejemplo en c# de lo que necesita, aunque sea minimo, algo  sumamente basico para que comienze con lo de la matricula. De paso siguiendo el comentario de Juan Salvado dejo este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/207794/107347).

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias por ese aporte crítico, soy nuevo aquí, de hecho hoy mismo me registré y no se que tan bien lo hago al dejar este tipo de respuestas, por supuesto haré lo posible por mejorar mis respuestas y no incluir solo enlaces con las respuestas sino un ejemplo de por medio.

Comment: Os agradezco mucho a todos vuestros comentarios, y de hecho me han servido para investigar y aprender, que no sabía por donde empezar... y así poder también aportar una posible solución como la de abajo... un saludo a todos!!

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime date;
private void ValidarFecha()
{
    if (error == false)
    {

        if (BoxFecha.Text == "  /  /")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("El campo 'Fecha' no puede estar vacío.",
                "Error en la introducción de datos",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            error = true;
            BoxFecha.SelectAll();
        }
        else
        {
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(BoxFecha.Text, out date))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El campo 'Fecha' no ha sido introducido correctamente.",
                    "Error en la introducción de datos",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                error = true;
                BoxFecha.SelectAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Por ejemplo, para validar la fecha. Una vez ya introduje la máscara de introducción de fecha correcta en propiedades ([MaskedTextBox.Mask](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_MaskedTextBox_Mask)).